# Has anyone a working example of using picasa web API on appengine with python nad OAuth2?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, gdata, picasa

The existing gdata python client library has documentation only for using AuthSub, but the [following link](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthSub) states that AuthSub is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

There's plenty of examples of other GData APIs using Python and OAuth2.0. For example: http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/09/python-oauth-20-google-data-apis.html